# UUPS upgradeable contract call fails with delegatecall error when calling newly added functions

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, delegatecall, upgrading, contract-upgrading

I created an upgradeable contract adhering to the UUPS standard following this guide [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/uups-proxies-tutorial-solidity-javascript/7786). I then added some new functions, deployed the upgrade using the upgrades plugin `upgrades.prepareUpgrade()` function to ensure the new implementation was compatible withe the existing one, then upgraded the implementation using the `upgradeTo()` function.
"Old" functions that existed prior to the upgrade are working as expected, but calling the newly added functions fails.

The revert message is: `Function must be called through delegatecall`.
I tracked this down to the proxy check:

```
modifier onlyProxy() {
        require(address(this) != __self, "Function must be called through delegatecall");
        require(_getImplementation() == __self, "Function must be called through active proxy");
        _;
    }
```

This is odd because the new functions are called in the exact same way as the existing functions. If it was really a proxy issue I would think the existing functions would fail as well.

To validate I tried deploying the new contract to a new address without doing an upgrade and that worked well.